# loading properties file in spring

Tags: java, spring

One of our team has implemented loading properties this way (see pseudo code below) and advises this approach is right as the client application using this is free to keep the properties in any file. Contrary to the widely used propertyplaceholderconfigurer.

### application-context.xml

```
<bean class="com.mypackage.Myclass">
<property name="xml" value="classpath:"{com.myapp.myproperty1}"> </property> 
</bean>
```

config.properties

```
com.myapp.myproperty1=data.xml
```

edit: I should have added it is data.properties and not data.xml. We want to load a property file (this property file is given in the config.properties as a "property".
com.myapp.myproperty1=data.properties

### java class

```
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
public class Myclass {

private Resource xmlField;

// setter & getter methods..

}
```

Is it right to use spring core.io.Resource?

Another reason is the client application wants to load a environment specific configuration. I suggested use the propertyconfigurer and use maven profiles to generate the environment specific build

Can you please advise which one suits which case? and if it differs in different scenarios,  please help me point out them?

thanks

Answer (score 10):

You can put the properties in any file and still use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. Here's an example that satisfies both your coworker's concerns and your desire for environment specific stuff:

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <!-- default settings -->
            <value>classpath:MyCompany.properties</value>
            <!-- environment-specific settings -->
            <value>classpath:MyCompany.${mycompany.env:dev}.properties</value>
            <!-- keep your coworker happy -->
            <value>classpath:${mycoworker}</value>
            <!-- allows emergency reconfiguration via the local file system -->
            <value>file:///${user.home}/MyCompany.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <!-- should be validated separately, in case users of the library load additional properties -->
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false"/> 
</bean>
```

If you pass in no `-D` arguments, then you'll pick up the following properties files, where properties in the later files overwrite previously determined values.

1. MyCompany.properties off the classpath
2. MyCompany.dev.properties off the classpath
3. $HOME/MyCompany.properties if it exists

To swap in a production config for #2, just pass `-Dmycompany.env=prod` to java. Similarly your coworker can pass `-Dmycoworker=/some/path/config.properties` if he/she wants.

Comment: I forgot to press submit on this answer, so now it duplicates some information that others have provided. Still, I'll leave it here in case anybody finds the additional details to be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurator` wouldn't have been the correct choice.

I've almost always handled environment-specific configs via a customized PPC that can either (a) get a `-D` parameter on startup, and/or (b) use the machine name, to decide which property file to load.

For me, this is more convenient than bundling the information in via Maven, since I can more easily test arbitrary configurations from whatever machine I'm on (using a `-D` property).

Comment: +1, I agree, unless *runtime* lookup is desired I think `ProperyPlaceholderConfigureer` or the `@Value(..)` approaches are to prefer.

Comment: edit: I should have added it is data.properties and not data.xml. We want to load a property file (this property file is given in the config.properties as a "property". com.myapp.myproperty1=data.properties
In short, load a property file whose location and name is in a property.
Can this be done?

Comment: @Sandeep You can create a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurator to look up values however you want, including reading from a property file to create its list of property file locations.

Answer (score 3):

+1 for Dave's suggestion. You should be using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer for loading\reading properties. Here is the example i just pulled out from my previous project if you wonder how to use this. This example is for loading multiple properties files but the concept is same. Good luck.

```
<bean id="projectProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:config.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="properties" ref="projectProperties" />
</bean>

<bean id="uniqueAssetIdRetriever" class="com.mypackage.Myclass">
    <property name="xml" value="${com.myapp.myproperty1}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Is the properties name "xml" is HashMap?